# macOS homebrew llvm clang tidy some checks are missing

Tags: llvm, homebrew, clang-tidy

I have installed LLVM via brew on macOS with the below mentioned command:

```
brew install --with-toolchain llvm@3.9
```

I would like to use `clang-tidy` but some checks are missing, for example misc-string-compare.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, misc-string-compare was introduced in LLVM 4.0